# remove Non checked items in a treeview

Tags: vba, ms-word, treeview

I have an treeview controller with checkboxes. I like to loop through this controller and to do the following: delete all non checked items.

my code (witch is not working) I received error 92 - For loop not initialized

```
Dim objNode As Node
Dim i As Integer

For Each objNode In Me.TreeView1.Nodes
i = i + 1
    If Me.TreeView1.Nodes(i).Checked = False Then Me.TreeView1.Nodes.Remove (i)
Next
```

Comment: Initialise i before using, also is the nodes array base 1 or 0?  i should be set accordingly.

Comment: you're using a loop, which returns an object from a collection, then referring to the collection with an incremented variable.  objNode is redundant or I is, pick a suitable method, objNode.Remove or controls.nodes(I).remove

Comment: I mean,the error is coming after one item is removed (the length of loop is change't)

Comment: If I use `objNode.Remove` I received error '438' - object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: If I used `Me.TreeView1.Nodes(i).Remove` I have Method or data member not found.

Answer (score 0):

I putted like this (and it is good for me):

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = Me.TreeView1.Nodes.Count To 1 Step -1
    If Me.TreeView1.Nodes(i).Checked = False Then Me.TreeView1.Nodes.Remove (i)
Next i
```